# gRPC How can I compile proto files from javanano ,use in Android?

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, grpc

```
protoc -I . --java_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-java_plugin=../../../grpc-java/compiler/build/binaries/java_pluginExecutable/java_plugin account.proto
```

I use this command to compile proto files, but is only generate "AccountOuterClass" file, Don't have "AccountGrpc" file , I don't know why, please help me fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `--java_plugin_out=.`. `--plugin` tells protoc where to find the plugin, but it doesn't cause protoc to run the plugin; the _out argument does that.

Note that --java_out is not for javanano. You would want to use --javanano_out instead. To enable javanano for gRPC, you should add nano=true to java_plugin_out: `--java_plugin_out=nano=true:.`

Also note that the plugin is no longer named "java_plugin" but instead "protoc-gen-grpc-java", so you may need to make sure the --plugin argument points to an executable file.

Take a look at the [compiler documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/compiler) for more info.